# Merge Sort Java Implementation so merge works within one array with second splitted array reversed

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

Challenge: within a lecture on data structures and algorithms I encountered a version of merge sort which uses the merge routine in a way that the second half is being reversed from the splitting index and from there compares the first and the last element. I tried to implement in java and it always failed somehow.

Problem: The array is being sorted so that the output is `[1, 2, 4, 8, 6]` so the `6` is not sorted. It seems as if the recursive call is not looking at the element `6` in the last `merge` call.

What I tried: Shifting different indices and adding different print statements for checking.
I tried to make `j = r` before the last `for` loop within `merge` which lead to *stack overflow* every time. I tried to change the way how the size of the array is being calculated, since I was not sure if the pseudo code excepts the array to start from 1 or 0. I tried to shift `if(p < r-1)` to `if(p <= r-1)` but get a *stack overflow*.

I looked at different implementations of java merge routine and every I found so far seems to work with two arrays. Is there a serious reason why the approach above is not working correctly or any idea how to fix this issue?

Given the following pseudo code:

```
void merge_sort(array<T>& A, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r - 1) {
        int q = Floor((p + r) / 2);
        merge_sort(A, p, q);
        merge_sort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}

void merge(array<T>& A, int p, int q, int r) {
    array<T> B(p, r - 1);
    int i, j;
    for (i = p; i < q; i++)
        B[i] = A[i];
    // Now i=q
    for (j = r; i < r; i++)
        B[--j] = A[i];
    i = p;
    j = r - 1;
    for (int k = p; k < r; k++)
        A[k] = (B[i] < B[j]) ? B[i++] : B[j--];
}
```

I tried to implement in java like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Mergesort {

    private static int[] A = new int[]{ 4, 2, 1, 8, 6 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        merge_sort(0, A.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }

    public static void merge_sort(int p, int r) {
        if (p < r - 1) {
            int q = Math.floor((p + r) / 2);
            merge_sort(p, q);
            merge_sort(q + 1, r);
            merge(p, q, r);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int p, int q, int r) {
        int[] B = new int[r - p];
        int i, j;
        for (i = p; i < q; i++)
            B[i] = A[i]
        for (j = r; i < r; i++)
            B[--j] = A[i];
        i = p;
        j = r - 1;
        for (int k = p; k < r; k++)
            A[k] = (B[i] < B[j])? B[i++] : B[j--];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the temporary array is too short: since `r` is the index of the last element, the size should be `r - p + 1`. It is much simpler to pass `r` as the index one past the last element of the slice to sort.
- the first `for` loop is incorrect: you should use a different index into `B` and `A`.
- the second `for` loop copies to `B[r - 1]` downwards, but it should use `B[r - p]` instead.
- the merging loop is incorrect: you should test if `i` and `j` are still within the boundaries of the respective halves before accessing `B[i]` and/or `B[j]`.
- [minor] there is no need for `int q = Math.floor((p + r) / 2);` in java as `p` and `r` are have type `int`, so the division will use integer arithmetics.

Here is a modified version:

```
public class Mergesort {

    private static int[] A = new int[]{ 4, 2, 1, 8, 6 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        merge_sort(0, A.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }

    public static void merge_sort(int p, int r) {
        if (r - p >= 2) {
            int q = p + (r - p) / 2;
            merge_sort(p, q);
            merge_sort(q, r);
            merge(p, q, r);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int p, int q, int r) {
        int m = q - p;  // zero based index of the right half
        int n = r - p;  // length of the merged slice
        int[] B = new int[n];
        int i, j, k;
        for (i = p, j = 0; j < m; j++)
            B[j] = A[i++];
        for (i = r, j = m; j < n; j++)
            B[j] = A[--i];
        for (i = 0, j = n, k = p; k < r; k++) {
            // for stable sorting, i and j must be tested against their boundary
            // A[k] = (i < m && (j <= m || B[i] <= B[j - 1])) ? B[i++] : B[--j];
            // stability is not an issue for an array of int
            A[k] = (B[i] <= B[j - 1]) ? B[i++] : B[--j];
        }
    }
}
```

Reversing the second half allows for a simpler merge loop without boundary tests. Note however that there is a simpler approach that uses less memory and might be more efficient:

```
    public static void merge(int p, int q, int r) {
        int m = q - p;  // length of the left half
        int[] B = new int[m];
        int i, j, k;
        // only save the left half
        for (i = p, j = 0; j < m; j++)
            B[j] = A[i++];
        for (i = 0, j = q, k = p; i < m; k++) {
            A[k] = (j >= r || B[i] <= A[j]) ? B[i++] : A[j++];
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you! is it really necessary to add logical operators to `A[k] = (i < m && (j <= m || B[i] <= B[j - 1])) ? B[i++] : B[--j];` I tested with `A[k] = ( B[i] <= B[j - 1]) ? B[i++] : B[--j];` and worked for every instance so far and I can´t see a reason why it should be problem if one index runs "into the other"

Comment: @FelixOuttaSpace: well, by removing the tests on the boundaries you lose the stability, but in case of `int` values, it does not matter in java. This only assumes `p < r` and seems to be the very purpose of reversing the second half.